# HTML5 Video working in all browsers except Safari

Tags: html, video

Trying to get a simple video to play on main page of website. I've included all three types of videos, and it works just fine on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. But no Safari.

Website can be seen here:
outoftheboxtechnology.appspot.com

```
<video id="my-video" playsinline class="video" muted loop autoPlay width="100%">
  <source src="/assets/media/six-points.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="/assets/media/six-points.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/assets/media/six-points.ogg" type="video/ogg"> 
</video>
```

Comment: Your mp4 video is sent as plain text. You need to configure your server.

Answer (score 0):

Safari 3.1+ supports it (Desktop).

Try this syntax

```
<video src="http://example.com/path/mymovie.mp4" controls></video>
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Hmm didn't seem to work. Thanks for your reply. I think the syntax is right, just not sure why it's not working.

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You [need Safari 4.0](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) to make the `<video>` tag to work. Perhaps you can put a notice on your website for your users. Once you meet that condition:

- Make sure your `src` (in your case `/assets/media/six-points.webm` etc) is valid and the source exists.
- Make sure you
  open the [Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) in your Safari and check if the tag is
  properly placed in the DOM.

Example:

```html
<section>
  <video id="my-video" playsinline class="video" muted loop autoPlay width="100%">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"   type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</section>
```

Comment: @blurtz can you try my code and if it does not work, can you present the entire HTML document?